# Bash alias com parâmetros

Tags: linux, bash

Estou criando um sistema que funcionara online, o usuário faz login e vai ter acesso a um terminal a qual o mesmo poderá executar somente os comandos permitidos no servidor. A questão é essa:

O usuário terá que executar um script em Python e passar parâmetros, então ele teria que dar o comando:

```
python arquivo.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Gostaria de ocultar o comando Python, sei que posso configurar o arquivo Bash adicionando Alias e no momento já configurei assim:

```
alias executarArquivo='python arquivo.py arg1 arg2 arg3'
```

Porém não funciona.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você tem algumas opções para passar parâmetros. A minha favorita é transformar o alias em uma função e tratar os parâmetros individualmente:

```
executarArquivo() {
    python arquivo.py "$1" "$2" "$3";
}
```

Nesta opção você tem acesso aos parâmetros pelo número, começando em `$1` (`$0` é o script que está sendo executado).

Outra forma de fazer isso é usando um alias (ou função) com a variável `$@`:

```
executarArquivo='python arquivo.py "$@"'
```

`$@` significa "todos os parâmetros" - o que pode ser bem útil se você não sabe quantos parâmetros serão passados ou está só criando um wrapper para outro script, como é o seu caso. Não esqueça as aspas.

Uma alternativa ao `$@` é `$*` que faz basicamente a mesma coisa (pega todos os parâmetros) com a diferença que `$@` traz cada parâmetro em sua própria string com aspas e `$*` traz todos numa única string.

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo, era exatamente isso que eu precisava.